# VL53L1X python library module not callable error

Tags: python

Hello i am trying to interface with my VL535L TOF module, but upon installing the library i am getting an error:

```
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/VL53L1X.py", line 3, in <module>
tof = VL53L1X.VL53L1X(i2c_bus=1, i2c_address=0x29)
  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

i have tried different source of library but the example code given throws that error.

- [VL53L1x pip](https://pypi.org/project/VL53L1X/)
- [VL53L1x pip3](https://pypi.org/project/VL53L1X2/)
- [VL53L1x github](https://github.com/pimoroni/vl53l1x-python)

here is the full code, i am using MU to create and run it.

```
import VL53L1X

tof = VL53L1X.VL53L1X(i2c_bus=1, i2c_address=0x29)
tof.open() # Initialise the i2c bus and configure the sensor
tof.start_ranging(1) # Start ranging, 1 = Short Range, 2 = Medium Range, 3 = Long Range
distance_in_mm = tof.get_distance() # Grab the range in mm
tof.stop_ranging() # Stop ranging
```

Comment: Works for me.  Perhaps add the instructions you used to install the library.

Comment: @joan im not quite following by what you mean,  what instruction are you refering to ?

Comment: "but upon installing the library".  How?

Comment: Hi @Jack, nice to meet you.  Ah let me see: The error of "VL53L1X.VL53L1X(...) is the type error: "'module' object is not callable" meaning that you are trying to ask the python interpreter to call the object "VL53L1X", the statement's second "VL53L1X" which is a method. I guess there might be a typo error: "VL53L1X" should read "vL53L1X", with a small "v".  Have a nice day.  Cheers.

Comment: @joan i followed the instruction on each library. for example `sudo pip3 install smbus2` followed by `sudo pip3 install VL53L1X2`.

Comment: @tlfong01 i have tried, changing it to small v, and it saying that it has no attribute. Im going to check the source code and look for this constructor (why did i not think of this earlier.)

Comment: I have checked the module file and it would seem that it is the correct syntax, so i tried to print the file location of the module thinking it imported the wrong file and returned me the path of the file i created (in desktop), it seemed to import itself not the actual module. I changed the file namee and now it throws me a diffeerent error `No module named 'VL53L1X'` .but am sure that i have installed the module, will investigate further

Comment: Ha, So you got a worse error message: "No module named 'VL53L1X'". Perhaps it is the python2/3, pip 2/3 incompatibility problem that causes all the confusion. Good luck and cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since after renaming the filname of the project file thrown me another saying that:

```
No module named 'VL53L1X'
```

It led me to manually add the path of the module to the file. I have modified the example code to this

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("VL53L1X", "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VL53L1X.py")
VL53L1X = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(VL53L1X)

tof = VL53L1X.VL53L1X(i2c_bus=1, i2c_address=0x29)
tof.open() # Initialise the i2c bus and configure the sensor
tof.start_ranging(1) # Start ranging, 1 = Short Range, 2 = Medium Range, 3 = Long Range
distance_in_mm = tof.get_distance() # Grab the range in mm
tof.stop_ranging() # Stop ranging
print(distance_in_mm)
```

I am now able to get distance reading which is not accurate but is a problem for another day.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: apologies, i kind of forgot to come back, it does not let you accept your own answer for 2 days.